# Examine the convergence of the following series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm really stuck with my homework in real analysis. Could anyone give me some ideas/tips or solutions, how to get these following tasks done? I would be very thankful!

> The task is to examine the convergence of the following series:

a) $$ \frac{1}{1} + \frac{10}{2} + \frac{100}{3} - \frac{37}{4} -  \frac{37}{5} -
 \frac{37}{6} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{10}{8} + \frac{100}{9} - \frac{37}{10} -
 \frac{37}{11} + \frac{37}{12} + \,...  $$

b) $$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k (ln(k^2+2)-ln \, k^2)\, arctan(1-k^2).     $$

Comment: Better to use \ln x for $\ln x$ and \arctan x for $\arctan x.$

Answer (score 1):

Hints: Show i) $\ln(k^2 + 2) - \ln (k^2)$ decreases to $0;$ ii) $\arctan(1-k^2) = -\pi/2 + O(1/k^2).$